# Problem Installing MiKTeX 2.9 under Windows XP Pro

Tags: installing, miktex

Every time I try to install the full distribution of MiKTeX 2.9 under Windows XP Pro, I get the following error message.

```
Installation: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
Loading package database...
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: "C:\Documents and Settings\Vasilios\My Documents\My Downloads\MiKTeX\miktex-2.9.4250"
visiting repository "C:\Documents and Settings\Vasilios\My Documents\My Downloads\MiKTeX\miktex-2.9.4250"...
repository type: local package repository
loading lightweight database...
lightweight database digest: 33d72d9ab13255850b97edbad0e46998

An error occurred:
  source file: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageInstaller.cpp
  source line: 3281
  message: The operation could not be completed because the following file failed verification:

C:\Documents and Settings\Vasilios\My Documents\My Downloads\MiKTeX\miktex-2.9.4250\hpsdiss.cab
  info:
```

If it's any help, the computer I am trying to install it on is connected to the internet via a wireless interface.  To obtain the distribution files, I have had to download them onto a computer connected to the internet via ethernet, and transferred them over using a memory stick.

Also, if it is any help, I downloaded the full distribution of MikTeX 2.9 from the following http server.

```
ctan.unsw.edu.au
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MiKTeX lists the `Integrity` of `http://ctan.unsw.edu.au` as `Unknown`. Perhaps try the `Intact` `ftp` protocol.

Comment: @Werner - I have already tried this resulting in may download failure attempts.  Either there was a loss of connection with the server, or a package failed verification.  Can you recommend another mirror server?  Thanks!

Comment: Check out [MiKTeX repositories](http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories). The problem *could* be a corrupt repository (hence the suggestions to change servers). As an alternative (via [a similar problem](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3308674&group_id=10783&atid=110783) as reference), [install MiKTeX 2.9 using the basic installer](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup), and update packages on-the-fly.

Comment: @Werner - Thanks, I will let you know how I go.

Comment: @Werner - Thanks for your advice!  I ended up installing the basic version of MiKTeX from the ftp site as you suggested.  Mind you, I did get a verification error on one of the packages while downloading, however, when I restarted the download process it ran smoothly till completion.  Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: I've included my comments as an answer, in order to keep the TeX.SX Q&A consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the latest [MiKTeX repositories](http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories) for a possible problem. The problem *could* be that the repository is corrupt (faulty update, incorrect checksums, etc). The solution then might be to switch to a different (intact) server, or different repository all together.

As an alternative (via [a similar problem](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3308674&group_id=10783&atid=110783) as reference), [install MiKTeX 2.9 using the basic installer](http://miktex.org/2.9/setup). Then, either update packages on-the-fly or add the packages as you need them.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me in Windows 7 is described in the MiKTeX Sourceforge bug ticket here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/1935/

... set the MiKTeX installer to Compatibility Mode Vista.

Comment: Note, that the question was for Windows XP. You should add a remark regarding your OS.

Comment: Hmm - you're right, I overlooked that.   I guess the original question was a year ago, maybe things have changed?   My experience (and others, looking around) is that Win7 (which I was referring to) has this problem, intermittently but "almost all the time".   The workaround I posted has worked every time, so far.  Hopefully at least my link to the miktex bug is adding value to this question/answer, for someone :)

Comment: I have Windows 7 here for some months and till today never observed this behaviour. (“Toi, toi, toi” as we say in Germany _grin_.)