# Lyx Installation Problem in windows 7

Tags: installing

I am trying to install Lyx 2.1.3 but at some point after MIKTEX it gives error : the operation could not be completed for the following reason, web browser could not be started. 
i have tried many times from the different links but it doesnt work... kindly help.

Comment: Did you try to install firstly MikTex and then LyX?

If this solution doesn't work either, try to install livetex. It is also compatible with LyX

Comment: also can have a look at this thread [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26703/problem-installing-miktex-2-9-under-windows-xp-pro?rq=1]